# Java Spring Boot REST API - Unresolved forward references for one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm currently working on REST API project in Spring Boot. I created two entities - Player and Team, and they are connected with one-to-many relationship.

Basically, the problem is when I try to create new Player, then new Team and assign Player to it. I do the following:

```
POST /players/

{
   "name": "Michael Jordan"
}

POST /teams/

{
  "name": "Chicago Bulls",
  "players": [1]
}
```

And then, I receive the following response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-26T17:18:11.383+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: \n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 43]Object id [1] (for `com.proglabs.nbaprojectrestapi.models.Player`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 41].",
    "path": "/teams/"
}
```

Code for models:

AbstractModel.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    protected int id;

    @Column
    protected String name;

    // setters, getters...
}
```

Player.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.*;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id",
        scope = Player.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
public class Player extends AbstractModel {

    @Column
    private LocalDate birthday;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Team team;

    // ...
}
```

Team.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id",
        scope = Team.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
public class Team extends AbstractModel {

    @Column
    private int championships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();

    // setters, getters, other columns ...
}
```

Code for controllers:

AbstractController.java

```
import com.proglabs.nbaprojectrestapi.models.AbstractModel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class AbstractController<T extends AbstractModel> {

    protected JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository;

    // ...

    @PostMapping("")
    public T create(@RequestBody T newEntity) {
        return repository.save(newEntity);
    }

    // ...
}
```

TeamController / PlayerController (relevant parts identical)

```
import com.proglabs.nbaprojectrestapi.models.Team;
import com.proglabs.nbaprojectrestapi.repositories.TeamRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/teams")
public class TeamController extends AbstractController<Team> {

    public TeamController(TeamRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // ...

}
```

I think that the problem might be in my understanding of how API should be designed, but my approach worked fine when I was using Jackson (without Spring) to just serialize/deserialize objects into/from json files.

I would really appreciate if somebody pointed me in the right direction. Sorry, if the question is asked in inappropriate way.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think your json needs to model your entity closer.  Have you tried posting json that looks like this

POST /teams/

```
{
    "name": "Chicago Bulls",
    "players": [
       {  "name": "Michael Jordan" },
       {  "name": "Joe Blogs" }  
    ]
}
```

I would also refrain from using abstract classes till you got it working.  Nesting classes can take extra mental effort to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that works, but what if I want to assign Player to existing Team?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add id-constructor to Player:

```
public Player(int id) {
  this.id=id;
}
```